# Empty ReadOnly-List using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a custom attribute, that is meant to mark a property to be erased before it is returned:

```
public HideAttribute:Attribute {}

public class UserData {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  [Hide]
  public string Phone {get;set;}
  [Hide]
  public List<Account> Accounts {get;} = new List<Account>();
}
```

Now the following code removes the data:

```
protected void Remove<T>(T someData) {
  foreach(var property in typeof(T).GetProperties()) {
    if (property.GetCustomAttribute<HideAttribute>==null) continue;
    Type t=property.PropertyType;
    if (property.CanWrite) {
      property.SetValue(someData,null) 
    } else if (property.CanRead && t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition==typeof(List<>)) {
      property.Empty(someData); // Pseudocode; There is no such method
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I want is: If the property is not writable, but is a list-type, I want to empty that list.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned with whether its a `List<>` type.  Just check to see if it implements the non-generic `IList` (or `ICollection`), which has a `Clear()` method.

Comment: But how? I can' just cast/call (((IList<>)property.GetValue(someData)).Clear()

Comment: Cast it to an `ICollection` and call `Clear()`.  Like I said, I wouldn't bother with the generic.  It gains you nothing.

Comment: still (ICollection<>)property.GetValue(data) also isn't valid ("unexpected use of unbound generic name")

Comment: I said `ICollection`, not `ICollection<>`

Comment: Point of correction: I was mistakenly looking at the documentation for the generic version of `ICollection<>`, not the non-generic.  The non-generic `ICollection` doesn't have a `Clear` method.  It will need to be `IList`.

Comment: It would probably be quicker (and a whole lot cleaner) to define a DTO and to map your object to this clean DTO version using Automapper. Also, if you don't want consumers to be able to consume the List why is it in the interface you give them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with generics; in this situation, using generics doesn't gain you anything, but it does make things harder.  `List<>` implements the non-generic [`IList` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist(v=vs.110).aspx), which has the `Clear()` method:

> public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
>       IEnumerable, **IList**, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>

That's all you need, after verifying you are, in fact, dealing with a `IList`.  To accomplish that, we use `typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(t)`, which checks to see if your property type is assignable to an `IList`.

Put together:

```
protected void Remove<T>(T someData) 
{
    foreach(var property in typeof(T).GetProperties()) 
    {
        if (property.GetCustomAttribute<HideAttribute>==null) 
            continue;
        Type t = property.PropertyType;
        if (property.CanWrite) 
        {
            property.SetValue(someData,null) 
        } 
        else if (property.CanRead && typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(t)) 
        {
            var collection = (IList)property.GetValue(data);
            collection.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. There is no `Clear` method in [ICollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

Comment: Woops!  You're right; I was looking at the generic version.  Fixed.

Comment: Gosh. Tried that. Intellisense said: "No way" and I tried another approach. Was simply missing Systems.Collection (instead of Systems.Collection.Generic) %-)